# How to get SubEdit under Windows 7 working?

Tags: windows-7, video, editing, subtitles

I need SubEdit Player to run under Windows 7.

But every time I try to start I get "Class not registered" error. Yes, I tried to install the Vista Patch, but doesn't work under Win 7.

Anybody got any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) instead, it has pretty decent support for playing movies with subtitles. Works fine on my Windows 7 64-bit install.

Comment: I'm not using SubEdit for displaying Subtitles, but editing subtitles.

For watching Movies with Subtitles I use GomPlayer

Comment: oh ok, you said "SubEdit Player" which I assumed was a module just for playing them

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest another program, [Subtitle Workshop](http://www.urusoft.net/products.php?cat=sw) is quite easy to use and has a wide range of features. One of the features I love is converting from different FPS rates if you, for example, get a video that plays at 24 FPS but your subtitles were created at 25 FPS.

It's easy to insert subtitles and type them as you go along with a few shortcuts, easy to adjust timings, and it can playback a video and display the captions as you type.

I'm a fan of it.

Comment: Aw, I didn't notice the question was 7 months old. Hopefully this will help somebody in the future.